# Import group from external blend file

Tags: python, groups

I have a .blend file that has a house group in it:

[image]

I'd like my script to be able to extract the house group from that file, then make duplicates of it in the current scene. I want to be able to position the duplicates etc.

The closest I could find is getting the meshes in the .blend file, here:
http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html

```
filepath = dir + "/somewhere/myHouseModel.blend";

with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.meshes = data_from.meshes
        for mesh in data_to.meshes:
            if mesh is not None:
                print("Mesh name: %s" % (mesh));
                ...
```

I suppose I could do something to just extract the meshes and work with that, but it would be nicer to properly link to the group. This is how I had it working manually in a standalone blend scene, so I'd like to mimic it via my python script.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17876/2217

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34540/how-to-link-append-a-data-block-using-the-python-api?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loads group "Head" from file mouth.blend.  The group can be added to the scene as a group instance.

```
with bpy.data.libraries.load("/home/batfinger/3DModels/mouth.blend") as (df, dt):
    dt.groups = ['Head']
```

In your case you will load group "house00" from file myHouseModel.blend

How to add a group instance is covered here [Add a group instance with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30737/add-a-group-instance-with-python)